# USB 3.0 drive not working in Kubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, external-hdd, usb-drive

I have a laptop that has USB 3.0 ports only and my portable HD doesn't work on it.
I have a desktop that runs the same version of Kubuntu and same kernel version but has USB 2.0 ports, the portable drive works fine there.

Portable Drive: Western Digital My Passport 1.0 TB

Kubuntu Version: quantal 12.10

Kernel Version: 3.5.0-17-generic

When I use `lsusb` right after connecting the portable drive, it is read. After 10 seconds it disappears.

`fdisk -l` doesn't see the drive at all.

Please note that I have installed `ntfs-config` and blacklisted `uas`.

**UPDATE:**
I plugged a USB 1.0 hub into the laptop and connected the Portable HDD through it, it worked. But the Portable HDD still doesn't work when connected to the laptop USB 3.0 port directly.

Answer (score 0):

Check if usb 3.0 is enabled in bios. 
On my computer (Dell precision) usb 3.0 was disabled by default, then only usb < 3.0 devices worked.